# What is the likelihood of security risk when MySQL Strict Mode is off

Tags: mysql, validation, security, my.cnf

Someone recommends STRICT_ALL_TABLES as one of the system hardening rules for the MySQL used for CMS. When it's set, the CMS prompted many INSERT errors. I understand that it validates data type especially for empty strings, 0 and nulls. I believe that data type checking is helpful for development. But what is its meaning on security?

Is this risk low?

Comment: In my opinion, data type checking is not useful for development. It's useful for security. It's because of security that it becomes useful for our development. When we run a method `close()`, for example, it would be good to know that it's really run on our `DatabaseQuery` object and not a `BankAccount`. [See this](http://www.pl-enthusiast.net/2014/08/05/type-safety/) for a very brief overview.

Comment: That's type safety. But system security here I mean, it's about the chances of being attacked

Comment: Type safety is correlated with an entire class of bugs. So by enforcing type safety, the attack surface is reduced.

Comment: You are right. I should refine the question: What is the likelihood of the security risk.